# How do i display one user current location to other on google map in android studio?

Tags: android, android-maps

I am developing an app using google map, I want show driver current location to his admin. How do i show driver current location to his admin? How do i trace driver current location and display to his admin?

Following code show only driver current location.In this how do i show this driver current location to his admin?

```
 //java code
    public class LocationActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
            com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener,
            GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

        private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
        private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; //1 minute
        private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

        private static final float SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT = 0.25F; //quarter of a meter
        Button btnFusedLocation;
        TextView tvLocation;
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        Location mCurrentLocation;
        String mLastUpdateTime;
        GoogleMap googleMap;

        private double longitude;
        private double latitude;
        private ArrayList<LatLng> points; //added
        Polyline line; //added

        protected void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT); //added
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }
        /*
        protected void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        }  */

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");

            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
            if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
                finish();
            }
            createLocationRequest();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_google_map);
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            googleMap = fm.getMap();
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        /*    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
                final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getBundleExtra("LOCATION");
                latitude = bundle.getDouble("LATITUDE");
                longitude = bundle.getDouble("LONGITUDE");  */

        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        }

        private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
                return true;
            } else {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
            startLocationUpdates();
        }

        protected void startLocationUpdates() {
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
            mCurrentLocation = location;
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            addMarker();

            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); //you already have this
            points.add(latLng); //added
            redrawLine();
        }

        private void addMarker() {
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

            // following four lines requires 'Google Maps Android API Utility Library'
            // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/
            // I have used this to display the time as title for location markers
            // you can safely comment the following four lines but for this info
            IconGenerator iconFactory = new IconGenerator(this);
            iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_PURPLE);
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon(mLastUpdateTime)));
            options.anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());

            LatLng currentLatLng = new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
            options.position(currentLatLng);
            Marker mapMarker = googleMap.addMarker(options);
            long atTime = mCurrentLocation.getTime();
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date(atTime));
            mapMarker.setTitle(mLastUpdateTime);
            Log.d(TAG, "Marker added.............................");
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(currentLatLng,
                    13));
            Log.d(TAG, "Zoom done.............................");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }

        protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                startLocationUpdates();
                Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
            }
        }

       // for map line
       private void redrawLine(){

           googleMap.clear();  //clears all Markers and Polylines
           PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
           for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) {
               LatLng point = points.get(i);
               options.add(point);
           }
           addMarker(); //add Marker in current position
           line = googleMap.addPolyline(options); //add Polyline

       }

    }
```

Comment: u need a backend server for this.

Comment: Do i save the location first and then display it?

Answer (score 0):

This might be one of the solutions 
1. Get the user's current location and update it on your server.

2. Use Firebase for your backend server.It makes lot of things easier.Store the user's location in firebase.

3. In Admin panel get the user's location from firebase.
You can use notifications to notify admin about user's current location once user has updated it in firebase.

Comment: can you pleaes refer me any example?